# redirect in laravel helper function

Tags: php, laravel

I have created function in laravel helper class to check Authentication in `app/lib/Auth.php`

```
class Auto extends \BaseController {

    public static function logged() {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $message = array('type'=>'error','message'=>'You must be logged in to view this page!');

            return Redirect::to('login')->with('notification',$message);    
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller

```
class DashboardController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        Auto::logged();
        return View::make('dashboard.index');
    }
```

I expect it redirect to login route if not logged, but it load `dashboard.index` view with message 'You must be logged in to view this page!'.

How can I redirect to login route with this message?

Comment: You realize that Laravel already has an `Auth` class with the same functionality as yours? [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security)

Comment: I would recommend using route filters to lock down areas to logged in users. Have a look at their documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Comment: I want to check Authentication and redirect to login page in one function if not logged, so I can use just one function instance of checking authentication in every function and send same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to create new helper function for that. Laravel already handle it for you. See `app/filters.php`. You will be see authentication filter like the following

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('/')->with('message', 'Your error message here');
        }
    }
});
```

You can determine if user is Authenticated or not like the following

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Read more about Authentication on [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security).

Answer (score 0):

this should be work :

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    if(Auto::logged()) {
       return View::make('dashboard.index');
    }
}
```